# Is there a way to configure protocol (tcp/udp) used in MS-SQL JDBC connection?

Tags: java, jdbc, mssql-jdbc

I'm using Microsoft JDBC mssql-jdbc-7.0.0.jre8.jar to connect to a 11.00.2100 MS-SQL Server. At this point I'm able to connect using DBeaver but can't connect using Tomcat or even a simple Java+JDBC class. These alternatives fail with timeout.

My JDBC URL is like this:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://thundercat.md.pt:1433;database=MYDBNAME;instanceName=MYINSTANCENAME;user=myusername;password=mypassword;loginTimeout=50;
```

My findings up to now are:

1. there must be something in the server config, because I have a similar server in the same network and I am able to connect. But I can't find out what (not very savvy on MS-SQL).
2. Although using the same JDBC driver, DBeaver connects in a different way than Tomcat or my simple class; using tcpdump I found out that DBeaver starts with an UDP connection to port 1434 and proceeds with a tcp connection between two random ports but my simple class always starts with a tcp connection to port 1433 instead, failing with timeout.

My code is very simple and it works if I just point to a different server, so it must have something to do with the network setup on this server and/or with this jdbc connection.

```java
String connectionUrl = 
       "jdbc:sqlserver://" + host + ":1433;" + "database=" + database + ";" +
       "instanceName=" + instance + ";" + "user=" + user + ";" + 
       "password=" + password + ";" +
       "loginTimeout=50;";

Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
```

Although these parameters work in DBeaver, they fail with timeout from Tomcat or my simple class.

This is the traffic for a successful connection with DBeaver:

```
10:01:13.649901 IP 10.10.1.5.50031 > 10.10.3.50.1434: UDP, length 16
10:01:13.650674 IP 10.10.3.50.1434 > 10.10.1.5.50031: UDP, length 101
10:01:13.652401 IP 10.10.1.5.55025 > 10.10.3.50.49831: tcp 0
10:01:13.652823 IP 10.10.3.50.49831 > 10.10.1.5.55025: tcp 0
10:01:13.653400 IP 10.10.1.5.55025 > 10.10.3.50.49831: tcp 0
10:01:13.653452 IP 10.10.1.5.55025 > 10.10.3.50.49831: tcp 67
10:01:13.654168 IP 10.10.3.50.49831 > 10.10.1.5.55025: tcp 31
10:01:13.656148 IP 10.10.1.5.55025 > 10.10.3.50.49831: tcp 273
...
```

And this is a failed connection from my jdbc class:

```
10:02:26.273941 IP 10.10.1.5.55074 > 10.10.3.50.1433: tcp 0
10:02:26.874860 IP 10.10.1.5.55076 > 10.10.3.50.1433: tcp 0
10:02:29.877173 IP 10.10.1.5.55076 > 10.10.3.50.1433: tcp 0
10:02:35.875310 IP 10.10.1.5.55076 > 10.10.3.50.1433: tcp 0
10:02:39.575984 IP 10.10.1.5.55086 > 10.10.3.50.1433: tcp 0
10:02:42.575554 IP 10.10.1.5.55086 > 10.10.3.50.1433: tcp 0
10:02:48.576195 IP 10.10.1.5.55086 > 10.10.3.50.1433: tcp 0
...
```

I'd like to understand how to configure the JDBC connection to make it work like DBeaver does.

Comment: DBeaver uses JDBC drivers as well, so apparently you are doing something different in DBeaver than in your code (different driver version, different URL). If I had to guess, your DBeaver variant is using a named instance instead of a port in its URL, which will cause the driver to query a lookup service (the SQL Server Browser service) for the right port for the named instance. You might want to include a screenshot of your DBeaver connection details.

Comment: The DBeaver trace shows that your SQL Server instance on 10.10.3.50 is listening on port 49831, not port 1433. Remove the port number from your connection URL and let the instance name resolve to the actual port number like DBeaver does.

Comment: Since I had both the port number and the instance name in dbeaver, I kept trying with both in the jdbc url. Apparently dbeaver knows the trick. Just by removing the port it started working. I suspected it would be a dumb thing like that... :-)